# What solutions exist to store data in text files and future-proof against tampering?

Tags: data, backup-archiving

A recent question in [Information and Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/),

> [How to know whether a textfile has been edited or tampered with](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110141/how-to-know-whether-a-textfile-has-been-edited-or-tampered-with)

raises a very good point: if one wants to archive experimental data in an open, text-based format, in the long term, it is desirable to have tools to prevent the tampering of the files, or at least detect the tampering if and when it happens.

The answers at infosec are good, but they feel somewhat abstract and hard to implement for a busy PI whose hands are already full trying to run a research lab. It may be, on the other hand, that solutions already exist that fulfil at least some of the requirements, or that they will appear not too long in the future; it's certainly reasonable to suspect that some form of tamper-resistant data or lab-book signature scheme is already in use at least in commercial research organizations.

This question is relatively hard to pose correctly, as there is an inherent vagueness in the requirements, and it is probably better to keep it general. The main problem is, given a set of text-based data files, how to signatures, or similar devices, that can be used in the future to provide guarantees that the data has not been tampered with. Are there any specific solutions that will do this in an accessible way?

Comment: Do you want to track changes (see: version control) OR do you want to ensure that a file is unaltered (e.g. due to malicious users, connection failures; see: md5 checksum)?

Comment: Also, if you haven't taken it into consideration for the storage, you'll want to look at ways to avoid/detect/correct for data rot.

Comment: I don't have anything particular in mind - I mostly think it's an appropriate time to have a parallel thread here to the InfoSec one, focused more on usable solutions than abstract signature schemes. I think both tamper-detection and change tracking solutions would be interesting in this context.

Comment: @E.P. What is your question here that is about academia?  This seems to me to still belong on infosec.

Comment: @jakebeal I suspect there is or will develop a market of tools geared directly at academics; in any case, as I said, academics tend to need plug-and-play solutions rather than abstract schemes that one could potentially implement oneself. In any case cf. [this](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/42669/) or [this](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/45801/) questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about information security, no part of which is specific to academia.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal, MD5 has been broken. Not enough to be able to doctor text files, but anyway. Use something else. You'd need a digital signature, like [PGP](http://www.pgpi.org) or [GPG](https://www.gnupg.org) offer.

Comment: Wow, you guys really are harsh.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to good recommendations on the *InfoSec SE* site, some of which are not that difficult to implement (for example, *digital signing*), I would suggest another rather straightforward solution (unless your data is extremely large or extremely sensitive): simply use one of **Git repositories**, such as *GitHub* or *GitLab*, or **research data repositories**, such as *Zenodo* or *figshare*.

Git and Git-based services now [support large files](https://git-lfs.github.com), plus you will have an added benefit of *versioning* for data files that you can match with your research workflows to enable *reproducibility*.

Check my [related answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/53983/12391) on some arguments for potential preference for *Zenodo* vs. *figshare*.

Comment: A private Github repository (they are in general very inexpensive) is my method of choice. They 1. Can be funded by your department with most likely no objections to the cost, 2. Allow for versioning of files with timestamps and version comparisons, 3. Offer collaboration features for your colleagues and have access controls if need be, 4. Are hosted so you don't have to worry about backing up data, 5. Are private to only the collaborators and can be made public if you feel like it. However, Github and similar services are don't work well with non-text data (no file diffs can be done).

Comment: @ChrisCirefice: Private repositories is what I implied in my answer (and, BTW, research data repository services offer them as well). As for diffs for non-text (binary) data files via Git services, your statement is not exactly true: 1) you can use Git attributes (see "Diffing Binary Files" on [this page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)); 2) for image files, there are various approaches, such as [GitHub's built-in one](https://help.github.com/articles/rendering-and-diffing-images) or [this one](http://www.akikoskinen.info/image-diffs-with-git).

Comment: The OP explicitly asks about text files, so Github should be good. Plus: I wouldn't trust any file format other than TXT and CSV to be legible in the long run. File formats change. Worst of all are proprietary file formats where you may not even have the necessary license in five years. Bottom line: store everything possible as TXT or CSV.

Comment: Unfortunately, using GitHub isn't really a long-lasting solution. It only lasts as long as Github's servers do, and depending on the success of a corporation isn't exactly future-proof.

Comment: @RogerFan: Your point is valid (in the context of long-term preservation). However, there are, at least, three approaches that alleviate the problem: 1) instead of hosted cloud versions, use of on-premise versions, i.e. GitHub Enterprise or GitLab EE; 2) deploying archiving solutions to several solid cloud infrastructures, i.e. Amazon Web Services, Microsoft Azure and Google Compute Engine, and keep data in sync (chances of all three companies disappear are pretty slim); 3) use Zenodo, which is built around CERN infrastructure and backed by EU, which guarantees the long-term data preservation.

Answer (score 6):

A common tools for checking data integrity is to use [MD5 checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). If you have unix-based system, you can do it form command line:

```
$ md5 some_file.csv
```

or (`md5sum`, depending on your system).

It gives some hexadecimal number (like `dc50353b4a1e5d99cb49b65e33b18916`) which will (almost certainly) change with any changes to the file.

Comment: The only problem with this is that you need to maintain a reliable  and trustworthy way of disseminating the correct hash to end users. In this short term this is pretty easy, but if you want to archive data for potentially years or decades it can be difficult.

Comment: @RogerFan Short term: just put md5 on your website. Long term: same, but in archive in which you are storing your data (and which archive is good is another question).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: Storing `md5` hashes where you store data files is akin storing keys in the open in the vicinity of locks they protect. Bad people can simply tamper data files and then regenerate corresponding hashes and replace the original ones with them, all in the same archive. Unless you track filesystem changes, you will have no idea that the data files have been tampered.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh No, it is not the best analogy. Unlike keys, you want to have as much people having a copy of it (which, in short, is the only way to ensure it is uncorrupt). And if you put your `md5` hash in article (publication) content, or some text, it is much more likely to be cross-archived that a (potentially big) file. What is ironic, git does not protect against malicious use (one force-push and you are done).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: I agree - it is not the best analogy. However, I was just trying to make a point, which, by the way, assumed a _centralized_ archival solution (perhaps, I misunderstood you, as I thought that was your assumption). Anyway, it seems to me that the solution you're talking about is _distributed_ and, thus, IMHO might be implemented, using _blockchain_ technology. As for potential malicious use of `git` via force-push, I don't understand how it could be malicious, if all repository operations are logged.

Comment: something... something... BLOCKCHAIN?